# How to iterate through a list passed to a function parameter with python?

Tags: python, opencv, increment

I am trying to use python to draw boxes at a large number of coordinates on an image with opencv and python. I have 2 lists that contain the coordinates of the start and end points of the boxes.

```
startxy = [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), ...etc.]  
endxy = [(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), ...etc.]  

cv2.rectangle(img, startxy[0?], endxy[0?], color, thickness)
```

I know I need to call the rectangle function over and over while I increment the index of my coordinate list, but I'm new to python and struggling with how to increment and pass these values to the rectangle function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the the zip of the two lists:

```
startxy = [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),...etc.]
endxy = [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),...etc.]

for start, end in zip(startxy, endxy):
    cv2.rectangle(img, start, end, color, thickness)
```